# PL\SQL varchar2 variable with null

Tags: sql, r, oracle, varchar

I have a query in SQL Developer and there is a record in a variable (varchar2) that is JOYABCD.
Looking into it usng notepad++ is written like: JOYnulABCD. So in reality there in a nul character between JOY and ABCD.

Is there a way in PL\SQL to get-rid of this nul?
I tryed with the following:
regexp_replace(name_variable, '\0', NULL)

but R says: nul character not allowed

Why, R say that? In slq it works and eliminate the nul character..

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: "In SQL it works and eliminate the nul character" is not true, how did you get that idea? Regular expressions can't handle the nul character. On the other hand, **standard** string functions have no problem with it. It is not clear what you need: an `update` statement to replace the existing value with the one where you remove the nul character? Or just a simple function for a `select` query?

Comment: Since you seem confused about this and you are not willing to accept what I am telling you: Here is the exact text from the standard, and a link to the standard. "The interfaces specified in POSIX.1-2008 **do not permit the inclusion of a NUL character in an RE or in the string to be matched.**  If during the operation of a standard utility a NUL is included in the text designated to be matched, that NUL may designate the end of the text string for the purposes of matching." Here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: By *there is a record in a variable*, did you mean *there is a column with a value*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string `str` contains `chr(0)` (the `nul` character), you can remove it from the string like so:

```
replace(str, chr(0))
```

This will be the same string, with every occurrence of `chr(0)` removed from it.

**Demo**:

Here I create a string `str` in a `with` clause, but in real life it should be your variable or column name. Then, I "replace" `chr(0)` with regular expression (which as you shall see does NOTHING), and with standard REPLACE. I use the DUMP function to show the actual characters in the strings. As you shall see, the fourth character is `nul` (value `0`) for the original string and the regexp result, but the 0 is deleted when I use the standard Oracle function REPLACE (not based on regular expressions).

```
with inputs as ( select 'JOY' || chr(0) || 'ABC' as str from dual )
select dump(str)                         as dump_str,
       dump(regexp_replace(str, chr(0))) as dump_after_regexp_replace,
       dump(replace(str, chr(0)))        as dump_after_replace
from   inputs
;

DUMP_STR                         DUMP_AFTER_REGEXP_REPLACE        DUMP_AFTER_REPLACE           
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- ------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=7: 74,79,89,0,65,66,67 Typ=1 Len=7: 74,79,89,0,65,66,67 Typ=1 Len=6: 74,79,89,65,66,67
```

Comment: I got it mathguys, thank you so much for your solution.

Comment: @user1010441 - Please note that the `'\0'` notation will not work in Oracle standard string functions. (It does work in regular expressions, but regular expressions can't handle the `nul` character, so they aren't useful in your case.) To handle the `nul` character in standard string functions you do need to concatenate `chr(0)` as shown here; `\0` will be interpreted verbatim, as a two-character string with no special meaning.